# Why if I add a pole at high frequencies to an improper transfer function it becomes realizable?

Tags: control, control-system

Suppose I have an improper transfer function, for example:

\$T(s)=\frac{s^2+1}{s+2}\$

I know that this transfer function is unrealizable. Moreover, I have seen that to make it realizable it is possible to make an approximation by adding a pole at high frequencies, so it becomes realizable.

Why if I add a pole at high frequencies to an improper transfer function it becomes realizable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long answer is [here.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Realizations)

The short answer is that the order of the numerator has to be less than or equal to the order of the denominator.

If this weren't the case a small amount of white noise at the input would generate infinite energy at infinite frequency.

Consider the simplest case of a differentiator H(s)=s.  The magnitude response increases without limit, so a physical system would need infinite energy to realize the response.

A real system like an op-amp differentiator for example will of course have poles at higher frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have one more doubt about my question, which is: why the pole has to be added at high frequnecies? I have tried simulations on Matlab, and seen that if I add the pole at higher frequencies, the pase margin and disturbance rejection increase, so the system behaves better.Searching I have found that a pole at high frequencies add robustness to the system, but why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as the transfer function being realizable the pole doesn't have to be at high frequency.  As far as a control loop goes as the frequency of the pole increases the phase lag associated with it within the control bandwidth decreases, so that could be what you're seeing.  A high frequency pole can also help with high frequency noise rejection.